# Yocto Raspberry4 image qemu emulation

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, qemu, raspberry-pi4

I have a problem with the emulated raspberry image (built in yocto) inside qemu. I know that qemu not support RPi4 so I found the qemu with patch
https://github.com/0xMirasio/qemu-patch-raspberry4, after compiling it I try to run qemu inside the docker container (previously I checked the same operation with RPi2 image and was ok

```
../qemu-system-arm -M raspi2b  -append "rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2" -cpu arm1176  -dtb bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb -sd 2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie.img -kernel kernel.img -m 1G -smp 4  -nographic
```

Now I trying do the same for RPi4 by execute:

```
./qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi4b2g -dtb bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb -sd core-image-full-cmdline-raspberrypi4-64.rpi-sdimg -kernel kernel8.img -nographic -append "rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2"
```

but nothing heppend, probably something with the kernel is wrong, but I dont know what.

Comment: You haven't given any error log. I don't know if `raspi4b2g` is supported on your qemu version or not. But on my version it doesn't. Check if your `qemu-system-aarch64` supports `raspi4b2g` or not.